# Setting javascript package directory in html

Tags: npm, mapbox

I installed mapbox gl js package with npm, and it's installed in in

```
/node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js
```

In html, how do I set path to the above directory in order to load the library correctly?
In my code, the directory is set as below

```
var mapboxgl = require('/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');In
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Mapbox GL JS quickstart page](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/overview/#quickstart) shows how to use the library. To reiterate from the linked documentation, once you have installed the npm package:

Include the CSS file in the  of your HTML file.

```
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.8.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Include the following code in the  of your HTML file.

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
// or "const mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl');"

mapboxgl.accessToken = /* YOUR MAPBOX ACCESS TOKEN HERE */;
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: '<your HTML element id>',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'
});
```

In general, the [Mapbox GL JS documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) is an excellent resource for similar how-to questions.